# R: detect duplicated row, and find out the count of each duplicated group

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I'd like to extract the link between the duplicated rows. I can find duplicated rows within one data frame, as

```
duplicated(df)

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[15] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[29] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[43] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[57] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I would like to find out the count of each duplicated case,

What I expected is of the format:

```
Row X --> Row Y, Row Z
```

which refers that X, Y, Z are duplicated, and the count of this group is 3.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. By default, `duplicated` determines "which elements [...] are duplicates of elements **with smaller subscripts**" (bold face mine). So in the case of two identical elements, the *second* identical element (with the larger index) will get flagged as `TRUE`.

Comment: Sure, but regarding the index, if row 1 is duplicated with row 7, and row 2 and row 3 are duplicated, then row 3 and row 7 will both be shown as 'TRUE', how can you know that row 3 is linked with row 2 or row1 only by looking at smaller index?

Comment: The expression fragment `== TRUE` is **always** redundant. Just leave it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many columns you have, this could be an option. You'd need to join on all the columns though:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
       col2 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
df <- data.frame(idx = 1:7, df)
df <- inner_join(df, df, by = c("col1" = "col1", "col2" = "col2"))
df <- df %>% filter(idx.y > idx.x)
df[, c("idx.x", "idx.y")]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to know the count of duplicated cases rather than remove them for a unique data frame.

Comment: A count of duplicated cases would just be the sum of the vector outputted by duplicated(). The above code would give you the linked row indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can apply unique() on your dataframe and compare this with the original dataframe. The r package "dfCompare" contains functions to compare records.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dfCompare/dfCompare.pdf